# Loop numbers with specific output for every multiples

Tags: php

can you guys please help me for this? I want to loop numbers from 1 to 100..
if the number is multiple of 4 it will print 'NEW', if number is multiple of 7 it will print 'TEST', and if the number is multiple of both 4 and 7 it will print 'NEWTEST'.

I've output the multiple of 4 and multiple of 7 but in both 4 and 7 I cant print the 'NEWTEST'.

Here's my code.

Thank you guys

function primeno($n){

```
 for($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++){

    if ($i % 4 == 0){

     echo 'easy<br>';
    }else if($i % 7 == 0){

     echo 'EMPLOYER<br>';
    }
    else  if($i % 4 == 0 &&  $i % 7 == 0){

     echo 'easyEMPLOYER<br>';

    }else{

       echo $i."<br>";
    }

  }

} 

primeno(100);
```

Here's my output:

```
1
2
3
NEW
5
6
TEST
NEW
9
10
11
NEW
13
TEST
15
NEW
17
18
19
NEW
TEST
22
23
NEW
25
26
27
NEW ----> it should be NEWTEST
29
30
```

No. 28 should be output 'NEWTEST' but instead it output NEW

Comment: oooh, good ol' fizzbuzz, prioritize conditions for both, then the first and second

Comment: and if  you want to include the hundred it should be less than or equal

Comment: im just a newbie. Just want to share the idea sir.. :( can you help me?

Comment: i already did, both comments answered it already, i'm not gonna spoonfeed everything (by modifying your code), this is fundamental in programming and you should understand it yourself, don't worry, you're close already, you only need small changes

Comment: thank you.. I dit it.. haha sorry for newbie question

Comment: sure no prob, glad it shed some light

Answer (score 0):

You just need to swap your conditions in your "if" and your last "else if" statements

```
<?php
function primeno($n) {
  for ($i = 1; $i < 100; $i++) {
    if ($i % 4 == 0 && $i % 7 == 0) {
      echo 'easyEMPLOYER<br>';
    }
    else if ($i % 7 == 0) {
      echo 'EMPLOYER<br>';
    }
    else if ($i % 4 == 0) {
      echo 'easy<br>';
    }
    else {
      echo $i . "<br>";
    }
  }
}
primeno(100);
?>
```